# Maximum number of lattice points with any two at least a fixed distance apart

Tags: combinatorics

Let $a$ and $n$ be positive integers. Consider an $an\times an$ lattice (i.e. points on a coordinate grid of the form $(x,y)$, where $x$ and $y$ are integers with $0\le x,y<n$). What is the maximum number of points on this lattice with the property that the distance between any 2 is at least $n$?